# Using secrets on pub/sub onMessagePublished event with GCP cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

Is it possible to use secrets dependency array(cloud functions v2) on an onMessagePublished?
It doesn't look like it has a parameter to accept that and I am getting errors if I try to include it as the handler.

exports.processMessage = onMessagePublished(
messageTopic,
{ secrets: [ApiKey, Secret, sqlUsername, sqlPassword, sqlServerName] },
async (event) => {}

Basically I want to use secrets in an onMessagePublished event. And in V2 functions they have to be on a dependency array

Answer (score 1):

For me the following workaround worked:

For the firebase pub / sub functions, I configured the secret through the console instead of adding it as a parameter in the function: *onMessagePublished*. The configuration is persisted, even when the function gets redeployed.

I followed this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/secrets#making_a_secret_accessible_to_a_function) to make the secret accessible to the function, here is an excerpt:

> **To make a secret accessible to a function:**
>
> 1. Go to the Cloud Functions page in the Google Cloud console: Go to the
>    [Cloud Functions page](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions?_ga=2.247926532.2002545001.1697879274-831339336.1697879274)
> 2. Click the name of the function you want to be able to access a secret.
> 3. Click **Edit**.
> 4. Click **Runtime, build and connections settings** to expand the advanced
>    configuration options.
> 5. Click **Security** to open the security tab.
> 6. Click **Reference a secret** to set a secret for the function.
> 7. Select the secret to make accessible. If you need to, [create a secret](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/creating-and-accessing-secrets).
>
>    - To reference a secret in the same project as your function:
>
>      a. Select the secret from the dropdown list.
>    - To reference a secret from
>      another project:
>
>      a. Verify that your project's service account has been [granted access to the secret](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/secrets#grant-access).
>
>      b. Select **Don't see your secret? Enter secret resource ID**.
>
>      c. Enter the secret's resource ID in the following format:
>
>      `projects/PROJECT_ID/secrets/SECRET_NAME`
>
>      Replace the following:
>
>      - **PROJECT_ID**: The ID of the project where the secret resides.
>      - **SECRET_NAME**: The name of the secret in Secret Manager.
> 8. Select the reference method for the secret. You can mount the secret
>    as a volume or expose the secret as an environment variable.
>
>    - To mount the secret as a volume:
>
>      a. Select **Mounted as volume**.
>
>      b. In the **Mount path** field, enter the path to use for your secret.
>
>      Do not reuse an existing mount path. Each mount path must be unique.
>
>      c. From the Version dropdown, select the version of the secret to
>      reference.
>    - To expose the secret as an environment variable:
>
>      a. Select **Exposed as environment variable**.
>
>      b. In the **Name** field, enter the name of the environment variable.
>
>      c. From the **Version** dropdown, select the version of the secret to
>      reference.
> 9. Click **Done**.
> 10. Click **Next**.
> 11. Click **Deploy**.
>
> Your function's code can now reference the secret.

I exposed the secret as an **environment variable** and access it in the pub / sub function using the following:

```
process.env.SECRET_NAME
```